# How to make a batch file to start a webpage if the current time = 9.00 AM

Tags: datetime, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file to load a webpage at a specific time using an `if` statement.

- I want it to load the program if the time is 8.55AM on a Friday.
- I also want it to continually check the time and date until it is.

I have come up with the following so far but it only reads and displays the time, not the date, and it does not use the time to open the program.

```
set CurrentDate=%DateDay%-%DateMonth%-%DateYear%-%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%
@echo off
@echo
echo.
echo %CurrentDate%
echo.
@echo off
IF %CurrentDate% == 08:55
start/MAX iexplore.exe"" "http://www.youtube.com"
```

Comment: use a task scheduler ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a loop like this:

```
@echo off
:no
set CurrentDate=%DateDay%-%DateMonth%-%DateYear%-%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%
echo.
echo %CurrentDate%
echo.
IF %CurrentDate% == 08:55 goto yes
timeout /t 30>nul
goto no
:yes
START http://www.youtube.com
timeout /t 61>nul
goto no
```

This will check every 30 seconds to see if it is the right time. and if it is then it will open your webpage. I have also made some improvements to the original code. P.S. you don't need another `@echo off` unless you use a `@echo on.`

Or try this:

```
@echo off
:no
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=:,. " %%i in ("%time%") do (
set hr=%%i
set mn=%%j
set sc=%%k
)
cls
echo %hr%
echo %mn%
echo %sc%
:Test1
IF %hr% == 8 goto Test2
timeout /t 30>nul
goto no
:Test2
IF %mn% == 55 goto yes
timeout /t 30>nul
goto no
:yes
START http://www.youtube.com
timeout /t 61>nul
goto no
```

Comment: Thanks, it counts for 30 seconds however it doesn't seem to use the CurrentDate so it continuously loops the "timeout /t 30".

Comment: It should brake the loop and open the webpage at 08:55. Set you time to 08:54 and wait.

Comment: thanks, it still isn't working correctly. It seems to be ignoring the IF statement.

Comment: Try the second code I have just added. I have tested it and it works on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `at` command:

```
At 08:55:00AM /every:Friday doSomething
```

Some examples are [here](http://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-at-command-examples/).